# How to take time as an input in Plotly Dash?

Tags: python, time, plotly, plotly-dash

in the latest version of Dash, there is a component for picking date.
I need a way to also take time as in input from the user, but currently there isn't any such component present in Dash, and the previous "time" as in input type is also removed.

Comment: You could use [dash-datetimepicker](https://pypi.org/project/dash-datetimepicker/).

Comment: See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714819/dash-plotly-datetime-selection