# Dash Plotly Datetime Selection

Tags: python, datetime, plotly-dash, datetimepicker

Is there anything in Dash world that gives a nice interface for inputting datetimes/timedeltas (doesnt matter what type, np, pd, dt etc)? I can only find code that really supports dates currently https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/datepickersingle. I am trying to create a plotting tool for real time sensor data, at the moment it runs in "streaming mode" with a set lookback, this just updates an animated graph every 2 seconds and "rolls" across the screen. I would also like to have a historical look and be able to set the start and end datetimes on the call to the database.

Comment: One way to go could be to make use of this nice Dash extension: https://www.dash-mantine-components.com/, which has both `DatePicker` and `TimeInput` component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimal example using html input type

```
from dash import Dash, dcc

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = dcc.Input(type="datetime-local", step="1")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

here `step="1"` gives seconds, the standard view seems to only give minutes (`step="60"` would give minutes, `step="3600"` hours, `step="0.001"` millis etc)

NB: This is not supported officially by dash https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/input

```
ALLOWED_TYPES = (
    "text", "number", "password", "email", "search",
    "tel", "url", "range", "hidden",
)
```

which means to run in debug mode you would need to turn off `dev_tools_props_check`

```
app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_props_check=False)
```

The main problem seems to be browser support
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#handling_browser_support