# Updating a figure in Dash based on Timestamp range selected by the end user

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am making an interactive dashboard using Plotly Dash and other libraries for Python. Among other things, my Dashboard will also have a simple line plot of the data shown below, which will update when the user changes the timestamp range.

I managed to create a DateRangePicker and then update the figure accordingly to the date range the user selects, but I see no option for Time range or timestamp range - even searching in the Dash documentation and on Plotly-Dash community forums, so I was wondering if it's somehow possible to do this in Dash? I would like to have a timestamp range *"from [Timestamp]"* - *"to [Timestamp]"* instead of the Date picker.

This is a snippet of my dataset:

```
    timestamp            date        id  lat         lon         mode   temperature
0   2022-04-01 13:48:38  2022-04-01  15  52.5170365  13.3888599  AUTO   33
1   2022-04-01 13:48:40  2022-04-01  15  52.5170365  13.3888599  AUTO   33
2   2022-04-01 13:48:42  2022-04-01  15  52.5170365  13.3888599  AUTO   33
3   2022-04-02 13:49:18  2022-04-02  15  52.5170375  13.3888605  AUTO   30
4   2022-04-02 13:49:34  2022-04-02  15  52.5170375  13.3888605  AUTO   30
5   2022-04-02 13:49:52  2022-04-02  15  52.5170375  13.3888605  AUTO   30
6   2022-04-03 13:50:10  2022-04-03  15  52.5170385  13.3888609  AUTO   31
7   2022-04-03 13:50:46  2022-04-03  15  52.5170385  13.3888609  AUTO   31
8   2022-04-04 13:51:24  2022-04-04  15  52.5170395  13.3888614  AUTO   34
9   2022-04-04 13:51:46  2022-04-04  15  52.5170395  13.3888614  AUTO   34
```

This is the example code I wrote for the date picker (and it works):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
import dash
import dash_daq as daq
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#df = #data shown above

app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id="date_filter",
            initial_visible_month=dt(dt.today().year, 8, 1).date(),
            start_date=df['date'].min(),
            end_date=df['date'].max(),
            show_outside_days=True,
            day_size=32,
            display_format='DD/MM/YYYY',
            clearable=True,
            style={'text-align':'left', 'width': '6', 'font-size': '10'}
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input("date_filter", "start_date"),
    Input("date_filter", "end_date"),
)
def updateGraph(start_date, end_date):
    if not start_date or not end_date:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    else:
        return px.line(
            df.loc[
                df["date"].between(
                    pd.to_datetime(start_date), pd.to_datetime(end_date)
                )
            ],
            x="date",
            y="temperature",
        )


# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

Comment: Have a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714819/dash-plotly-datetime-selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with dropdowns in the past. If you need hour and minutes just divide them into 2 dropdowns and it gets quite easy to operate with them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Dash component available for selecting timestamps ranges which you can find here: https://pypi.org/project/dash-datetimepicker/

Usage:

```
dash_datetimepicker.DashDatetimepicker(
        id='date-time',
        startDate = '2022-04-01 13:48:38',
        endDate = '2022-04-04 13:51:46',
        # utc = True/False
        # locale = es/en/de etc...
    )
```

[image]